# ORA-03135: connection lost contact when using Django ORM

Tags: oracle, django-models, multiprocessing, cx-oracle

I have a scenario: I am using multi-processing design in my django application to write information to the same table. However, i keep getting this error:

Exception occured while inserting data - ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error
&
Exception occured while inserting for Node Hourly - The database did not return a new row id. Probably "ORA-1403: no data found" was raised internally but was hidden by the Oracle OCI library (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28859). => What i did here is to attempt to get the ID for the model i just created & inserted into the DB.
&
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03135: connection lost contact

I have no idea how to resolve this issue. On the surface i expected that Oracle will manage the incoming processes as independent instructions. But truly I do not know what is going on and how to solve it.

I tried googling for people with the same issues, but so far it led me to dead ends.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the exact version of Oracle you are using, and what is the exact SQL statement being submitted? ORA-01403 should not cause ORA-03106 or ORA-03135.

Comment: Using Oracle 12c, and i use django orm's model .save()

Comment: Can you say more specifically which version? 12.1? The precise SQL is important because there is a known bug in Oracle 12.1.0.2 that could cause this, but you would have to know the SQL to confirm the bug. There is a work-around, but you would then have to change the SQL being submitted. https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2226243_1.html

Comment: 12.1.0 to be exact sir